# How to compare values in pandas pivot_table with different indices?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Pivot Table:

```
COURSE          ENGLISH       MATH       ART
STUDENT              

StudentA        95.0          83.0       97.0
StudentB        91.0          93.0       47.0
StudentC        85.0          84.0       92.0
StudentD        97.0          84.0       85.0
StudentE        93.0          88.0       85.0
StudentAvg      94.5          83.7       96.9
```

I want a list of students who have a grade more than `5%` lower than `StudentAvg` by subject. So in this case I'd want something like:

`English: StudentC
 Math:
 Art: StudentB, StudentD, StudentE`

How can I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns a list of tuples that show which student and in which subject had a grade more than 5% less that the average.

```
avg = df.loc['StudentAvg', :]
i, j = np.where(((df / avg) - 1) < -.05)
list(zip(df.index[i], df.columns[j]))

[('StudentB', 'ART'),
 ('StudentC', 'ENGLISH'),
 ('StudentC', 'ART'),
 ('StudentD', 'ART'),
 ('StudentE', 'ART')]
```

---

We can speed up a bit with

```
p = df.index.get_loc('StudentAvg')
v = df.values
i, j = np.where(((v / v[p]) - 1) < -.05)
list(zip(df.index[i], df.columns[j]))

[('StudentB', 'ART'),
 ('StudentC', 'ENGLISH'),
 ('StudentC', 'ART'),
 ('StudentD', 'ART'),
 ('StudentE', 'ART')]
```

---

**Timing**

```
%%timeit
p = df.index.get_loc('StudentAvg')
v = df.values
i, j = np.where(((v / v[p]) - 1) < -.05)
list(zip(df.index[i], df.columns[j]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.7 µs per loop

%%timeit
avg = df.loc['StudentAvg', :]
i, j = np.where(((df / avg) - 1) < -.05)
list(zip(df.index[i], df.columns[j]))\
1000 loops, best of 3: 662 µs per loop
```

Comment: Are you telling me it took 417 and 662 seconds respectively for the calculation? Or do you mean you did 10000 iterations, and those were the best averages?

Comment: @NishantRoy no!  41.7 microseconds and 662 microseconds respectively

Comment: 41.7 microseconds for the entire code-block to run, right? Or are you saying that much time per loop, and the code-block takes 10,000 loops .

Comment: @NishantRoy 10,000 loops ran. The fastest 3 of those loops took an average 41.7 microseconds

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT:

```
df.apply(lambda x: str(x.name)+ ': ' + ', '.join(df[((x-x.loc['StudentAvg'])/x.loc['StudentAvg']*100<-5.0)].index.tolist())).values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['ENGLISH: StudentC', 'MATH: ', 'ART: StudentB, StudentC, StudentD, StudentE']
```

Let's use this:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: (x-x.loc['StudentAvg'])/x.loc['StudentAvg']*100<-5.0).any(axis=1)
df[mask].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['StudentB', 'StudentC', 'StudentD', 'StudentE']
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear before. I wanted a list by `Subject`, just added an example to the post. Could you modify your answer to do that?

Comment: @NishantRoy I modified the solution.